# Docker cp maven package into running container by maven

Tags: docker, maven, tomcat, maven-antrun-plugin

For local development I'd like to copy a maven war package into a docker container right after `mvn package` has created the package. How can I accomplish this?

My workflow as of right now is with a specific dockerid:

```bash
$ mvn clean package
$ docker cp the.war dockerid:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/the.war
```

A Tomcat server in the docker container recognizes the new war and starts again.

I tried adding the maven-antrun-plugin. However, the war is not deployed, whether I use it in the install or package phase. I get no error or warning with e.g. `mvn clean package`. However, `the.war` file is not copied into the docker container.

Below the dockerid is hardcoded momentarily.

```
   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.jdk>1.8</version.jdk>
        <version.maven.compiler>3.6.1</version.maven.compiler>
   ...
   </properties>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <exec executable="docker">
                                    <arg value="cp"/>
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/target/the.war"/>
                                    <arg value="dockerid:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/the.war"/>
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please give much more details what exactl is not working because based on that: `the war is not deployed, whether I use it in the install or package phase.`...

Comment: @khmarbaise  updated that I get no error or warning with e.g. `mvn clean package` and that `the.war` file is not copied into the docker container.

Comment: That `A Tomcat server in the docker container recognizes the new war and starts again.` contradicts what you are asking for? I'm completely puzzled? Please give more details what you have done and what exactly are the erroor/ etc. btw. why using a running docker container and deploying inside a container? Why not rebuilding the container ?

Comment: A very common setup for Java images is to work mostly locally, and have a Dockerfile that only `COPY`s a prebuilt jar file into an image.  Recreating the container from the new image would restart Tomcat.  Would this setup work for you here?  IME running `docker cp` is somewhat unusual and I wouldn't expect it to be part of your core workflow; there's no particular reason to try to preserve the one container.

Comment: There are several third party libraries that I copy into the docker image, when its build. The build of the docker container needs about 8 minutes. I do not analyse the tomcat start, because this needs to be done either way. However, a maven package alone is done in 2.5  minutes, the copy process by hand is negligibly fast. So I would save about 5 minutes with this dev workflow.